# Soundcloud SC.Stream encountering a TypeError

Tags: javascript, soundcloud

I'm attempting to run the following in Safari/Chrome on desktop

```
SC.stream("http://api.soundcloud.com/groups/55517/tracks", {limit: 1}, function(sound){
    sound.play();
});
```

but am getting the error

```
soundManager.createSound(): Unavailable - wait until onready() has fired.
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

I have run the code with a breakpoint, and `sound` is being assigned to `false`. I have downloaded soundmanager2.js and placed it with my JavaScript/HTML files.

Disclaimer: Complete JavaScript novice.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem as shown

```
soundManager.setup({
  onready: function() {
    SC.stream("http://api.soundcloud.com/groups/55517/tracks", {limit: 1}, function(sound) {
      sound.play();
    });
  }
});
```